# i don't understand 一人分

Tags: manga

I can't understand a sentence. Could you help me please ?

> アンタ一人分くらい私の稼ぎで回せるっての

i don't understand "一人分"
I understand that as "I paid your expenses with my income"

The previous sentence is "言っとくけど１円も使ってないわよ" and she just told her nephew that his father gave money to pay for his studies. 
Does "一人分" have any other meaning than "one person's portion"??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1人分 here does mean "one person's portion", and in this context it refers to one person's worth of living expenses, i.e., the living cost of アンタ, which the speaker thinks is small enough.

And do you understand what 回せる means here, which is critical to catch the meaning of 1人分? This 回せる is the potential form of 回す, which has a slangy meaning "to manage", "to moderate (party, etc)", "to run (shop, etc)", "to keep going", etc. (Surprisingly, this meaning is not in jisho.org.) In this context 回す means financially making ends meet and keeping the family together.

> アンタ一人分くらい私の稼ぎで回せるっての
>   It's just one person's worth (of living expenses), I can make ends meet (only) with my wage!
>   I can at least afford one person's worth (of living expenses) with my income!